# 'jsp:getProperty' Cannot find any information on property 'name' in a bean of type package.Class error

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans, getproperty

I am trying to implement the jsp:useBean tag. Here are the following files. A simple name retrieval is to be performed.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Controller.do" method="post">
Enter Name: <input type="text" name="userName"><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller.java class

```
package foo;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Controller extends HttpServlet{

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String s=req.getParameter("userName");
    PersonEmployee p=new PersonEmployee();
    p.setName(s);
    req.setAttribute("person",p);

    RequestDispatcher view=req.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
    view.forward(req, resp);
}
}
```

I am using a secondary class on purpose just to check the saving and retrieval through JSP.

PersonEmployee.java

```
package foo;

public class PersonEmployee {

private String name;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name=name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

}
```

I am getting an error in the following jsp file. 
Error: [Cannot find any information on property 'name' in a bean of type 'foo.Controller']
I am still not able to identify the error in the 'name' attribute of the 'getproperty' tag.

result.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="person" class="foo.Controller" scope="request"/>
Name is: <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this in result.jsp page `class="foo.PersonEmployee"`

Comment: and where is your servlet declaration? in web.xml?